# Calculating integral with residuum theorem.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can I calculate the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4} + 1}{x^{4} - 1}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{2x} dx$

I tried separating it on two domains:

a) 0 to 1 which holds x = 0 as a simple pole and also observed that it is even.

b) 1 to infinity, in which i can't seem to find any pole.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that there is actually no pole at $x=0$, since $\sin(x)$ linearly approaches zero in the vicinity, so that the ratio $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is finite. However, there *is* a pole at $x=1$, where the denominator $\frac{1}{x^4-1}$ blows up. The way you wrote the integral, your integration contour runs smack into this pole. You'll have to specify how your contour approaches the pole from the left and from the right if you want to make sense of this integral.

Comment: Why do you think this integral even converges?

Comment: Never heard of a "residuum" theorem. If you mean the "Residue theorem", there is a lot more you have to consider. For the residue theorem, you need to integrate *around a closed curve in the complex plane*, which you do not have here. You can double this to get an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ since integrand is even, but the common method of closing the curve with a half-circle does not work here, as the integral over half-circle cannot be shown to go to $0$ as the radius goes to $\infty$.